# Typescript Code for Searching and Filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter the input of the user's search query, so that if they type the specific name of what they are looking for, only that thing returns.

I have an Angular2 demo app (http://mazzoangular2.azurewebsites.net/) I am working on that simply returns the search results that are a search for an artist's work. Right now it is returning all paintings that contain that the first letter entered.

Here is the typescript search code:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'find'
})

export class SearchPipe {

  transform(pipeData, pipeModifier) {
    return pipeData.filter((eachItem) => {
      return 
eachItem['name'].toLowerCase().includes(pipeModifier.toLowerCase()) ||

eachItem['shortname'].toLowerCase().includes(pipeModifier.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}//End class SearchPipe 

SearchPipe.prototype.transform = function (pipeData, _a) {
    var pipeModifier = _a[0];
    return pipeData.filter(function (eachItem) {
    return 
eachItem['name'].toLowerCase().includes(pipeModifier.toLowerCase()) || 
eachItem['shortname'].toLowerCase().includes(pipeModifier.toLowerCase());
    });
}
```

Comment: ok, and what's wrong with your code?

Comment: You can go to this link to play with it http://mazzoangular2.azurewebsites.net but, the issue is the search logic doesn't seem to be drilling down to the specific name if entered directly.  Such as if you type the name that is suggested in the search input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        SearchPipe.prototype.transform = function(pipeData, _a) {
            var pipeModifier = _a[0];
            return pipeData.filter(function(eachItem) {
                return eachItem['name'].toLowerCase().includes(pipeModifier.toLowerCase()) || eachItem['shortname'].toLowerCase().includes(pipeModifier.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
```

In your code, you're only evaluating with the first character of pipeModifer.  Your filter logic is working, it's just that when you search with 'Blah' it's only using 'b' and discarding the rest of the search.

This is happening because in your declaration of your transform function, you are passing pipeModifier as the first element of an array.  In typescript, this means it is assuming the 2nd argument of pipeModifier is an array and you want pipeModifier to be the first element of that array.  You can fix this by just changing

```
transform(pipeData, [pipeModifier])
```

to

```
transform(pipeData, pipeModifier)
```

Example of how Typescript converts this to Javascript:

Typescript Function

```
function test(var1, [var2, var3]){
    console.log(var2);
}
```

Resulting Javascript Function

```
function test(var1, _a) {
    var var2 = _a[0], var3 = _a[1];
    console.log(var2);
}
```

No matter how large of an array, it'll only use the first two elements.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  So I am adding that transform function into my code to modify the search results? I can place that function above the export class declaration?  Thanks...

Comment: Added an explanation to the original post

Comment: Peter I have updated my original post to reflect changes to the code I worked in that you suggested. You can go to this link to play with it mazzoangular2.azurewebsites.net but the search function doesn't seem to be drilling down to the specific name if entered directly. Such as if you type the name that is suggested in the search input field in the app.

Comment: Delete the bottom part from 'SearchPipe.prototype.transform = function (pipeData, _a) {'.

I was showing the converted Javascript, you don't actually want that part in your .ts file.

Comment: Peter thanks a bunch your suggestion works.  How can I become as good as you with Angular?  I want to know stuff like what typescript is assuming, and how it converts itself to JavaScript.  Thanks again. CM

Comment: It just takes time.  You can see how Typescript converts into Javascript by viewing the resulting .js file.  If you have a Program.ts and you compile it (or your IDE does it for you), there will be a Program.js file in the same directory, where you can see what the typescript code turned into.

Comment: Peter thanks.  After I made the change you suggested, and it worked locally, I then tried to deploy to Azure, and I got the dreaded HTTP 502.5 error.  If you have some time could you check out the issue and I'd be interested in what you have to say about a potential solution. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348112/publish-to-azure-app-service-failing-iis-502-5-error